# Rails One to Many association, adding data to many using post ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, parameters

I have a one to many association in Rails. Song has many channels and channel belongs to song. I am trying to create a new song with 6 channels. Here is my form in front end:

```
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: ,url
                dataType : 'json', 
                data : $("#form").serialize(), 
                success : function(data) {
                    var newSong = new Object();
                    newSong.song_name = data.sn;
                    newSong.singer_name = data.ss;
                    newSong.genre = data.sg;
                    newSong.channels[0].url=data.u1;
                    newSong.channels[1].url=data.u2;
                    newSong.channels[2].url=data.u3;
                    newSong.channels[3].url=data.u4;
                    newSong.channels[4].url=data.u5;
                    newSong.channels[5].url=data.u6;
                    },
                error : function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },})});});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">

Song Name: <input id="sn" type="text" name="song_name"><br><br>
Singer Name: <input id="ss" type="text" name="singer_name"><br><br>
Genre: <input id="sg" type="text" name="genre"><br><br>
Url 1: <input id="u1" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
Url 2: <input id="u2" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
Url 3: <input id="u3" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
Url 4: <input id="u4" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
Url 5: <input id="u5" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
Url 6: <input id="u5" type="text" name="url"><br><br>
<input id="submit" type="button" name="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

As you can see from my code my form field has all inputs named url and that causes the problem, but when i change the name back end does not recognise it as permitted parameter.Here is my songs-controller create action:

```
def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)
    @song.save

    @ch1 = Channel.new(channel_params1)
    @ch1.song_id=@song.id
    @ch1.save


    @ch2 = Channel.new(channel_params2)
    @ch2.song_id=@song.id
    @ch2.save

    @ch3 = Channel.new(channel_params3)
    @ch3.song_id=@song.id
    @ch3.save

    @ch4 = Channel.new(channel_params4)
    @ch4.song_id=@song.id
    @ch4.save

    @ch5 = Channel.new(channel_params5)
    @ch5.song_id=@song.id
    @ch5.save

    @ch6 = Channel.new(channel_params6)
    @ch6.song_id=@song.id
    @ch6.save

    respond_to do |format|
    if @ch6.save
      format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @song }
    else
      format.html { render :show }
      format.json { render json: @song.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  end

private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def song_params
    params.permit(:song_name, :singer_name , :genre)
    end
    def channel_params1
      params.permit(:url)
    end
    def channel_params2
      params.permit(:url)
    end
    def channel_params3
      params.permit(:url)
    end
    def channel_params4
      params.permit(:url)
    end
    def channel_params5
      params.permit(:url)
    end
    def channel_params6
      params.permit(:url)
    end
end
```

NOTE:My action is successful to set one url, however urls of all 6 channels are set to the last form entry so I get same url for all 6.

Answer (score 0):

As you've deduced, the names of your inputs are not correct. I didn't make the connection that you aren't using templates or Rails views. The trick with the naming is that you include the index in the name:

```
<input id="u1" type="text" name="url[0]">    
<input id="u2" type="text" name="url[1]">
```

and so on. Rails will group those into an array of strings for you similar to:

```
{ url: ["your.first.url", "your.second.url,...]}
```

There will be more to the params than that, of course--you'll have the channel wrapping that stuff as well. I have no insight into the overall shape of your models and that's what will dictate that shape.

Comment: The problem is I am not using view part of rails I am using front end jquery and react for that part.

Comment: ah, okay. that makes sense. The trick here is to build the input name with the index IN the name. For example  `<input id="u1" type="text" name="url[0]">`  Rails will extract that into the params as a list of urls, something like `{ "url" => [ <url_0>, ...]}